# How to Inject Retrofit using Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to implement MVP pattern using Dagger2. While I successfully did di for application, activities and for fragments (I'm not sure I did well with fragments). Actually after reading guides I still don't understand how it works.

I created RetrofitModiule:

```
@Module
public class RetrofitModule {
     String mBaseUrl;
...
@Provides
@Singleton
Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
}
```

Then I declare module in MyApplicationComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                MyApplicationModule.class,
                RetrofitModule.class
        }
)
public interface MyApplicationComponent {
     void inject(MyApplication myApplication);
     Retrofit provideRetrofit();
}
```

Actually I don't understand why I have to use Inject here; Because there nothing to actually inject into MyApplication:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private MyApplicationComponent mMyApplicationComponent;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mMyApplicationComponent = DaggerMyApplicationComponent.builder()
            .retrofitModule(new RetrofitModule("https://androidtutorialpoint.com"))
            .build();
        mMyApplicationComponent.inject(this);
    }
}
```

I use Retrofit only in LoaderActivityPresenterImpl which injected to LoaderActivity;

```
@ActivityScoped
public class LoaderActivityPresenterImpl implements LoaderActivityPresenter {

private LoaderActivityView mView;
private @ActivityContext Context mContext;
private Retrofit mRetrofit;

@Inject
public LoaderActivityPresenterImpl(LoaderActivityView view, @ActivityContext Context context, Retrofit retrofit) {
    mView = view;
    mContext = context;
    mRetrofit = retrofit;
}
}
```

LoaderActivity:

```
public class LoaderActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoaderActivityView{

@Inject LoaderActivityPresenter mPresenter;
private LoaderActivityComponent mLoaderActivityComponent;

@Override
protected void setupActivityComponent(MyApplicationComponent myApplicationComponent) {
    mLoaderActivityComponent = DaggerLoaderActivityComponent.builder()
            .myApplicationComponent(myApplicationComponent)
            .loaderActivityModule(new LoaderActivityModule(this, this, myApplicationComponent.provideRetrofit()))
            .build();
    mLoaderActivityComponent.inject(this);
}
```

LoaderComponent:

```
@ActivityScoped
@Component(
    modules = LoaderActivityModule.class,
    dependencies = MyApplicationComponent.class
)
public interface LoaderActivityComponent {

void inject(LoaderActivity loaderActivity);

}
```

LoaderActivityModule:

```
@Module
public class LoaderActivityModule {

private Retrofit mRetrofit;
private LoaderActivityView mLoaderActivityView;
private @ActivityContext Context mContext;

public LoaderActivityModule(LoaderActivityView loaderActivityView, @ActivityContext Context context, Retrofit retrofit) {
    mLoaderActivityView = loaderActivityView;
    mContext = context;
    mRetrofit = retrofit;
}

@Provides
LoaderActivityView provideLoaderActivityView() {
    return mLoaderActivityView;
}

@Provides
public @ActivityContext Context provideActivityContext() {
    return mContext;
}

@Provides
public LoaderActivityPresenter LoaderActivityPresenterImpl() {
    return new LoaderActivityPresenterImpl(mLoaderActivityView, mContext, mRetrofit);
}

}
```

LoaderActivityComponent:

```
@ActivityScoped
@Component(
    modules = LoaderActivityModule.class,
    dependencies = MyApplicationComponent.class
)
public interface LoaderActivityComponent {

void inject(LoaderActivity loaderActivity);

}
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.xxxxx.application.MyApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.xxxxx.di.modules.MyApplicationModule must be set;
```

I can probably forget to show some classes, so feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you forget to add your ApplicationModule to your component.
By the way, I highly suggest you take a look at [AndroidInjector](https://google.github.io/dagger/android), to avoid creating this Android component hierarchy manually.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private MyApplicationComponent mMyApplicationComponent;
...
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mMyApplicationComponent = DaggerMyApplicationComponent.builder()
        .myApplicationModule()
        .retrofitModule(new RetrofitModule("https://androidtutorialpoint.com"))
        .build();
    mMyApplicationComponent.inject(this);
```